# expected singleton error in odoo accounts tree view

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

```
data = [{'account_type': u'account_type', 'balance': 3484382.4899999998, 'type': 'report', 'name': u'Assets', 'level': 1}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 87301.78, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100101 Cash', 'level': 4}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 257350.98, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100201 HDFC Bank', 'level': 4}]
@api.multi
def account_fun():
      for item in data:
           return item['balance']
```

i'm calling that function using compute and getting the error expected singleton. but i want store all the balance from data into the database by one by one. in account.account table in odoo .

```
balance = field.Float(string="Balance",compute="account_fun")#creating new balance field.
```

how can i do that.and have to show balance field in list view. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with that logic, I have just give you idea here how you can do it.

```
data = [{'account_type': u'account_type', 'balance': 3484382.4899999998, 'type': 'report', 'name': u'Assets', 'level': 1}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 87301.78, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100101 Cash', 'level': 4}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 257350.98, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100201 HDFC Bank', 'level': 4}]

@api.multi
def account_fun(self):
    for rec in self:
        balance =0
        for item in data:
            balance += item['balance']
        rec.balance = balance

balance = field.Float(string="Balance",compute="account_fun")
```

> You are getting this error because in self list of recordset will be
>   there. In new api there is different way to set the functional field
>   which I have described above.

Comment: here getting only value in the list view(every row), but i need different value in row. like 3484382,87301.78

Comment: This is why I have mention first, I didn't understand what you want to set in balance. If the balance field is functional then how it should be calculated you need to specify that point. However you will never get data in list of dictionary as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.multi
def account_fun(self):
    data = [{'account_type': u'account_type', 'balance': 3484382.4899999998, 'type': 'report', 'name': u'Assets', 'level': 1}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 87301.78, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100101 Cash', 'level': 4}, {'account_type': u'liquidity', 'balance': 257350.98, 'type': 'account', 'name': u'100201 HDFC Bank', 'level': 4}]
    for rec in self:
        for j in range(len(data)): 
            if rec.code in data[j]['name']:
                rec.balance= data[j]['balance']

balance = fields.Float(string="Balance",compute="account_fun")
```

thanks @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. ,some what changed your code getting what i want.